# Ignoring JARS the ugly way via classloader

Tags: java, jar, classloader

So, I am trying to do something ugly here, let's say it's a desperate measure as I cannot have control over the runtime environment.

So having that said, I run some code in an environment where I cannot have control over the classpath (bad thing)... What's still worse is that the classpath has two jars, let's say productV1.jar and productV2.jar Both are exactly the same, but in different versions, so they have same classes.

For some reason, in most environments the productV2.jar is loaded and the productV1.jar is left out, but in some other environment, productV1.jar is called, and it causes the program to crash.

What I want to do as a workaround is mess with the classloader to explicitly ignore "productV1.jar". Ideally by overwriting some classloader funtion. I have done this with other resources (like the persistence.xml file from Hibernate), but I don't want to filter based on containing classes, but rather on the jar file. Is there a way?

This is only meant to work until I can do the negotiations to get rid of the offending jar...

Edit: I will leave this question open in case there is some interesting hack. However, the issue is that everything that is in the classpth is loaded by the system classloader, and trying to switch it at runtime is not an easy task (or maybe not possible at all?). Only way I see is starting the process with a custom classloader, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I think one should avoid doing such things even when having good reasons for it but the question is interesting from the perspective "what is possible in theory?"

Comment: Your real problem is not technical, it's your environment. Can't you talk to whomever controls setting the classpath to resolve the problem? Workarounds like this just make the problems worse.

Comment: In fact, I am taking care of the environment, but since it takes time, I thought it would be fun to find a short term hack... But I'm finding out that it will not be easy...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) and manually add jars to the classpath? In constructor of URLClassLoader you pass an array of URLs which point to jars that you want to load.

You can make the following experiment: create an URLClassLoader subclass that includes only the jars you want (i.e. call super constructor with appropriate array of URLs) <s>and then call your java with the following property:</s>

`-Djava.system.class.loader=test.CustomJarsClassloader`

To set your classloader as the default one.

The classloader may look like:

```
public class CustomJarsClassLoader extends URLClassLoader{
  public CustomJarsClassLoader(){
    super(new URL[]{ /*List of URLs to jars... */});
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

Ok, if you can't add this argument to command line then try another approach:

1. In your main() function create a new Thread
2. Set the classloader that I mentioned above as this thread's context classloader (see: [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setContextClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29))
3. Run all your application's code inside this Thread. Your classloader should be used to load classes.

Comment: If he can't change the classpath what's the chance he can add any additional arguments to calling the java runtime?

Comment: Exactly... My hope was to be able to do something on runtime. It was more a hope for a hack, but I even tried changing the classpath of the system classloader using reflection (which worked), but it seems it loads classes way before I can mess with it... :)

Comment: @Martin All right, I updated my post with another approach. Maybe it would help?

Comment: @PiotrSobczyk, I was wanting to avoid this, but since I can extract the full classpath from the system classloader, I can filter it and then create a new one based on the correct list. Issue is that it will be used for unittests, so probably I will need to create a new testrunner, will see if I can get this to work without messing with testcode...